# Android OS 6.0 nulling static variables

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, low-memory

I have bunch of traces in Google Play where it seems that static members of application class are null.

All the related posts I found are about storing data, but these variables are not data, they are 3rd party SDK instances or other crucial objects which use singleton pattern along with the application.

Data used in `Activity` classes are stored into database and no static references are used there.

These traces do not get reported to Fabric at all which is weird since it's initialised in `Application` `onCreate` method.

The trace indicates that static variable is null when `FirebaseMessagingService` `onMessageReceived` method is triggered, there I need to pass the message to 3rd party SDK but since the instance of that is null the app crashes.

**Traces only seen with Android OS 6.0**

Are there any solutions on how to deal with this OS version being so aggressive nulling static members?

Thanks.

Here is example minimum code of my usage:

Application class:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Engine.init();
}
```

Engine class:

```
private static Engine sInstance;

private 3rdParty m3rdParty;

private Engine() {
    m3rdParty = new 3rdParty();
}

public static void init() {
    if (sInstance == null) {
        sInstance = new Engine();
    }
}

public static onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    sInstance.m3rdParty.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    // Above line crashes with NPE, sEngine or m3rdParty is never set to null in code
}
```

Extended FirebaseMessagingService:

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Engine.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
}
```

Comment: Android does not null static fields.  Can you post your `Application` class along with the details of how those singletons are initialized?

Comment: In one place it looks like your singleton is named `sEngine`; in another, `sInstance`.  Could this be the problem?

Comment: Your singleton is not thread safe, but it wouldn't need to be if you're only accessing it in the main thread.  Is there any asynchronous stuff you removed from your posted code?

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede sorry was a typo, can you tell me more about this thread safety?

Comment: Because `sInstance` isn't `final` or `volatile`, if you set it in one thread (in this case the main thread) and read it in another thread, the other thread is not guaranteed to see the value you wrote.  But code that isn't thread safe almost always still works, which is what makes thread safety bugs so hard to identify.

Comment: Maybe thats the issue here, push notification is not triggered in main thread, and this OS 6.0 handles the memory little bit different than other OS versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are there any solutions on how to deal with this OS version being so aggressive nulling static members?

The "OS" is not "nulling static members". Most likely, your process is terminated, whether due to low memory conditions or user action (e.g., swiping your task off the overview screen). This is perfectly normal.

I say "most likely", because your question does not contain a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), with the stack trace and related source code, and so I cannot preclude other possibilities. For example, if you have code that assigns `null` to those `static` fields under certain conditions, perhaps those conditions are being met in cases that you are not expecting.

Comment: Posted code how my application class, engine class and push service interact. So if static members are never nulled, can the non static member inside static object get nulled?

Comment: @Niko: Only if you assign `null` to it. Perhaps somebody is playing with a hacked version of your app where they disabled your `Application`. If this code is real, I would get rid of `Engine.init()` and use [a proper thread-safe lazy-initalization pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking#Usage_in_Java).

Comment: There are hundreds of traces pointing to this same trace and all of them have OS 6.0 in common (LG, Sony, Samsung + other manufacturers). So I believe there is either something wrong in that above code or something weird in that specific OS version.

Comment: I can change the pattern of Engine class, but I still have no idea what is wrong in the above code causing the NPE when push message is received and Engine.onMessageReceived() gets called.

Comment: @Niko: I would start by testing your code to see how it behaves when your process is terminated. You can terminate your process from Android Studio's Monitor tool (circle with an X in it in the tool strip). Then, send your app an FCM message, and see what happens. BTW, if you are using multidex, you may need to reorder some of your stuff so that the FCM code and the `Engine` code are in the same DEX file. I haven't played much with multidex, but I seem to recall some discussion about keeping common initialization things together.

Comment: Lets hope this is about thread safety like kevin pointed out in comments, tested terminating the process and sending push, works normally with this LGE Nexus running OS 7.1.1

Comment: Yes this is multidex application, I will refactor the Engine class and include the dex options to force Application and Engine class to main dex file. If that doesn't help we shall see in another post :)